# Example of uniform tree lattice?

Tags: graph-theory, trees, lattices-in-lie-groups

I'm reading about uniform tree lattices. Let $X$ be a locally finite tree and $G$ its automorphism group. A subgroup $\Gamma\leq G$ that is discrete and such that $\Gamma\setminus X$ is finite is called a uniform tree lattice.

I'm having trouble coming up with a simple example. What would be the simplest (nontrivial) examples of a uniform tree lattice?

Comment: Do you know what a free group is? What about its Cayley graph?

Comment: Yes I know what those are. But I don't know what the automorphism group of the Cayley graph is. Could you explain a little more? What can I take $\Gamma$ to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let $F_n$ denote the free group on $n<\infty$ generators, $X$ the Cayley graph of $F_n$ with respect to the free generating set. Then $X$ is a locally finite tree (its valence equals $2n-1$), the group $F_n$ acts on $X$ freely and $X/F_n$ is a finite graph $R_n$, the wedge of $n$ circles. ($X$ is the universal cover of $R_n$.) Therefore, $F_n$ acts as a uniform tree lattice. Other interesting examples come from finite amalgams of finite groups, e.g. 
$$
Z_n \star Z_{2m} \star_{Z_m} Z_{2m}$$ 
etc. The book "Trees" by Serre is a classic treatment of group actions on trees. The book

"Tree lattices'', by H. Bass and A. Lubotzky, with appendices by H. Bass, L. Carbone, A. Lubotzky, G. Rosenberg, and J. Tits, Prog. Math., vol. 176, Birkhauser Boston, Inc., Boston, MA, 2001, xiv + 233 pp.

is another good reference.

Comment: So what is your $\Gamma$ here? We are supposed to take $\Gamma$ a subgroup of the automorphism group of $X$. Does the free group somehow embed in this automorphism group?

Comment: @nullUser: Yes, free group acts as an automorphism group on its Cayley graph; same for any group: any group acts by automorphisms on its Cayley graph. Do you know the definition of a Cayley graph?

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with the Cayley graph and how $F_n$ acts on it by left multiplication. I think I'm understanding now. Associate each $x \in F_n$ with the graph automorphism $v \mapsto x.v$. Then $\Gamma$ is this set of automorphisms? I think I am missing something though. Why is the valence of $X$ equal to $2n-1$ and not $2n$? Doesn't every vertex have an edge for each generator and each inverse of a generator?

Comment: @nullUser: Yes, it is 2n, do not know why did I write 2n-1.